# How to merge two MPEG files wih PHP

Tags: php, mpeg

I'm using the Google Text-to-Speech to make a game, but the TTS have a limit of 100 characteres per request.  So, I split the text, and I do more than one request to synthesize the complete text.

Now, I have the binary of sound of my text split in two files.

Just doing a simple

```
$audio1 .= $audio2
```

doesn't work.

The file type is MPEG, so it's not the same as MP3.

I think I need to clear the headers of the second file, but I dont know how to.

Comment: Can you tell me how you downloaded Google Translate Speech?
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=Something does not work

Comment: You can request this URL

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q='.YOUR_TEXT_HERE.'&tl='.YOUR_LANG_HERE

this will return a audio/mpeg if the text have less than 100 characteres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test using your URL, it generates MP3 files, after a lookup on Google it could be done:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iwbzqdvsxymytgu/c2SaOVjcHY (Hosted on Dropbox for Audio files)

Comment: I have found this class too. But i think it just work for MP3 files.

If you see, your word.mp3 have 0 bytes. OR it fails upload to Dropbox.

And have tested the Mpeg audio file in the Windows Media Player and it worked.

Its only dont work in Flash Web player.

If i success, i post the code here.

Comment: It has 0bytes cause is outoput file, generate it to see working (last line on index.php)
I made both 1 and 2 mp3 files using your URL, concatenated they both using this Class and then saved on output (may ask for saving)
Tested if working using RhythmBox

Comment: A simple string concat works in others browsers

    $audio1 .= $audio2;

The problem only occurs in Firefox and Opera. I dont know why. IE, Chrome, Opera, all plays the merged mpeg properly. And its weird, because all uses Flash Player.

But its solved for a while. Thanks for helping.

Comment: This method striptags dont work properly. Your code generate the same error on Firefox. The way that i found is generate the mp3 or mpeg files using the concat way. And convert the audio with Adobe Media Encode. Then, the audio files are fixed and play well in all browsers.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) tool to process media files, [example concat two files](http://ulyssesonline.com/blog/2009/12/03/concatenate-video-files-using-ffmpeg/)

Comment: There is no way by using simple PHP ?